# Write unit test for "ActivationEnd" event from router.events.subscribe in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router, angular-router-events

I need help in order to write unit tests for `router.events.subscribe`. I used `ActivationEnd` to use snapshot object which has properties which I need for my application. No other events from router provide these so I have to stick to this `ActivationEnd`. But I did not get anything so far as to how to mock this [snapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) object.

Below is my code snippet.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof ActivationEnd) {
        this.section = e.snapshot.data.title;
        this.dynamicSubNavLabel = e.snapshot.routeConfig?.data?.label;
      }
    });
  }
```

Can you please help me what could I do to achieve unit tests for this or any alternatives ?

Regards,
Alpesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say, you have a component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-router',
  templateUrl: './test-router.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-router.component.css']
})
export class TestRouterComponent implements OnInit {
  section = '';
  dynamicSubNavLabel = '';
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof ActivationEnd) {
        this.section = e.snapshot.data.title;
        this.dynamicSubNavLabel = e.snapshot.routeConfig?.data?.label;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Because `Router.events` is a `Subject<Event>` already. We can do this:

- We'll cast it to `Subject<Event>` then call `next` to emit our custom/mock ActivationEnd Event.
- Casting our mock data to unknown first, then casting to ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ActivationEnd, Event, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { TestRouterComponent } from './test-router.component';

describe('TestRouterComponent', () => {
  let component: TestRouterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestRouterComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ TestRouterComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestRouterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should update data from router', () => {
    const events$ = router.events as Subject<Event>;
    const mockSnapshot = {
      data: {
        title: 'some heading'
      },
      routeConfig: {
        data: {
          label: 'some text'
        }
      }
    } as unknown as ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
    events$.next(new ActivationEnd(mockSnapshot));
    expect(component.section).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.dynamicSubNavLabel).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

Source code from Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/75a3c778b1f7be913f0287423d40fade68ee9adc/packages/router/src/router.ts#L461

Comment: Great Tiep... It worked but I changed only one line to  "const events$ = router.events as Subject<any>;" instead of Event as it was throwing lot of errors... But you deserve bounty so thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use a mix of jasmine.createSpyObj and json object maybe this will help you:

```
 const activationEndMock = {
    ...jasmine.createSpyObj(['']),
    snapshot: {
      data: {
        title: 'a title'
      },
      routeConfig: {
        data: {
          label: 'a label'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const routerMock = {
    ...jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>(['']),
    events: of(activationEndMock)
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: routerMock }]
    });
    .........
  });
```

I'm not sure this will work because I didn't test it.

Comment: I am getting an error "createSpyObj requires a non-empty array or 
object of method names to create spies for throw" for line "...jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>([''])"

Comment: Remove the two single quotes:
...jasmine.createSpyObj([]),

Comment: Also after removing quotes, I have the same error.

Comment: Point to be noted: I need to mock this line... e instanceof ActivationEnd... so activationEndMock is still returning an object and not an instance...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118808/mock-class-object-for-condition-instance-of-to-be-true-in-unit-testing-angular .... some more modification on above question